# Sys scema and Information schema permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, security

I have SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have denied SELECT on all [sys] schema, and INFOMRATION_SCHEMA objects for a user.

But the user has to be able SELECT from INFOMRATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS,
but despite the REVOKE:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON OBJECT::[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[PARAMETERS] to myUser;
```

the user still cannot select from that table/view.

I guess I have to REVOKE more, previously DENIED permissions on those system views/tables, but not sure which.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not another [sys] table, but DENY VIEW DEFINITION permission which blocked me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON OBJECT::[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[PARAMETERS] FROM myUser;
```

Note the change with keyword `FROM`. Examples are shown on Microsoft's website [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187719.aspx)

Comment: sorry thats a typo i made ... i think its still a list of sys tables which i have to make visible to the user again, but not sure which sys tables ...